# ionic 3 sidemenu display data from local storage

Tags: ionic3, ionic-native

Am new to ionic and developed simple app which users have login access. when a user login am saving his data in localstorage. then showing information in sidemenu. my problem is when new user login first time no data is displaying sidemenu. but he close app open again its working fine.

Comment: Share your sample code. Then we can find where you made mistake.

Comment: can u share link